# notify a thread in the client that was send on wait() in the server

Tags: java, concurrency, client-server

I have a big problem to resolve and I don't know how to resolve it. In a thread server I call on a object the method `wait()` after using `ObjectOutputStream` send the object to a client thread that is connected to the server. When the object arrives on the other side I call on the object the method `notify()` but the object doesn't wake up from his state of waiting. This is caused because the object sent it isn't the same. How can I resolve this big issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Irrespective of whether the client and server are on two different machines / JVMs, the object you get after serialization - deserialization is different than the original object.
When you call "wait()" on one object, the thread blocks until some other thread call notify() on the SAME object.
You are having two different objects here and so, wait-notify mechanism won't work.
You have to send some acknowledgement to the server using network communication ( sockets may be).

Comment: You have to send some acknowledgement to the server using network communication.Well is what I think to do...

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, you are serializing an object on the server, sending it to a client, calling `notify()` on the client, and expecting that to affect the server. This won't work because they are on different computers, or at least different JVMs. The only way you can send a message back to the server is through your socket.

Comment: Zahniser I'm testing this application on the same JVMs creating the socket for the client Socket socketClient = new Socket("localhost",port_number) and ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port_number), and not in two different machines

Comment: If the "server" and "client" threads are on the same JVM, you can pass the object directly without using a socket (say, by adding it to a queue that is polled by the client thread). If you need the object to go through a socket, a copy will be made on the other end and the only way to send a notification back is through the socket.

Comment: @Mazzy if you have JVM*s* they aren't the same. You need both objects to reside in one JVM to make `notify` work as you expect.

Comment: @VictorSorokin I have only one JVM I made a mistake

Comment: @RussellZahniser I have to pass the object through the socket.but when the object arrives on the other side is not anymore the same object it was called on the server, right?

Comment: @Mazzy: That's correct, the deserialized object is just a copy of the original. So, just send a message back through the socket and have that be what wakes up the server.

Comment: @RussellZahniser but in the server there will be the object in the waiting state so if i send the notify to wake up, the server will receive it?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to read the documentation about [synchronization](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html).